# Nginx try_files (folders + files) fallback

Tags: nginx

Given this folder structure:

```
root folder
    + default
        + settings1.txt
        + settings2.txt
        ...
        + settingsN.txt
    + user00001
        + settings1.txt
        ...
    ...
    + userN
        + settings1.txt
        ...
```

And this example url:

```
domain.com/user00009/settings1.txt
```

Or

```
domain.com/xavi/somefile.txt
```

I would like to write a rule that let me do:

```
folder exists ? check file : 404

file exists ? serve users file : serve default file
```

I tried using try_files but I think I can only use $uri i get the whole url, would be great if I could work with the slugs ( $1 = user00009 & $2 = settings1.txt )

Then maybe I could put:

```
location / {
   root /...
   try_files $1/$2 default/$2 =404;
}
```

Any idea?

**Note: I know i could server the files from outside nginx ( in this case django ) but Im trying to speed things up**

Answer (score 10, accepted):

```
location ~ ^(/[^/]+)(/.+)$ {
  root ...;
  if (!-d "$document_root$1") {
    return 404;
  }
  try_files $1$2 /default$2 =404;
}
```

Comment: Thanks @Alexander, I know this may be regex related, but what if the folder and file names are not named with patterns? instead of user0001:alexanderazarov and instead of settings1.txt:finance.txt?

Comment: Seems this line:

if (! -d $document_root$1) {

Is giving me an error :S

Comment: Is there a problem to make regex less specific? Please see my edits. I've wrapped the condtion's argument into double quotes as well, but frankly I'm not sure nginx allows `$document_root` in this context. You better try these edits, but probably you'll have to write `/var/root$1` instead

Comment: Partially working, I had to remove the space between ! and -d ( before: !_-d now: !-d ) in the first condition and add a ";" after the =404. try_files is not working... Is there any chance I can see what nginx is doing? (step by step) looks it cannot reach the folders... maybe $1 and $2 are wrong? do they need slash? $1/$2/

Comment: Thanks! I've fixed the answer. No, you don't need slashes, because regexp captures them. My recommendation is to keep `error_log` level at least at `notice`. And if you set error_log severity to `debug`, Nginx will write a lot of debugging information per every request.

Comment: OK. I found it thanks to your advise putting on debug mode. Awesome :) you deserve to be the solution. BUT, you must add a slash before (/)default$2 in order to be the correct answer :)

Comment: Oh, yes, you are right. Fixed the answer. Glad you have everything working.