# NGINX try_files Fallback

Tags: http, nginx, server

I have this folder structure:

```
/document/root/
|-- main
`-- wishlist
```

I want to get my nginx to work like this: If I point my browser to `example.com/wishlist` it will display the `index.html` on the `wishlist` folder. If I point my browser to `example.com`, I want it to fallback to `main/index.html` (and, of course, related `main/style.css` and other files that are in the main directory).

I don't want to write a location rule for every folder I have under my root, so I want this to be as generic as possible. I have found [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9286341/nginx-try-files-folders-files-fallback) questtion and it has helped me to get most of the job done, but there's something not working: if I point the browser to `wishlist/index.html` it works perfectly. But if I remove the `index.html` and point it just to `example.com/wishlist` the browser will return a 404. My current Nginx config is below. Can someone point me in the right direction? Thanks.

```
server {
    listen 80;
    listen [::]:80;
    server_name example.com www.example.com;
    root /document/root/main;

    location ~ ^/([^/]+)(/.+)?$ {
        if (!-d "$document_root/$1") {
            return 404;
        }
        try_files /$1$2 /main$2 =404;
     }
}
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Turns out I found out a way that worked for me: using a custom `@location` on nginx. My final piece of code turned out something like this:

```
location / {
    root /document/root/main;
    index index.html;
    try_files $uri $uri/ index.html;
}


location ~ ^/(.+)$ {
    root /document/root;
    index index.html;
    try_files $uri $uri/ index.html @main;
}

location @main {
    try_files /main/$uri /main/$uri/;
}
```

Now `example.com` uses `/document/root/main` as it's root and `example.com/wishlist` uses `/document/root/wishlist` :) Hope this helps someone else.

Answer (score 2):

All you need to do for the index file is:

```
index index.html

location / {
    try_files $uri.html $uri/index.html =404;
}
location /wishlist {
    try_files $uri.html $uri/index.html =404;
}
```

Comment: Thanks for the answer, @Rob, but I have other folders (and I'll be adding more folders in the future) and I didn't want to have to deal with editing the nginx file everytime I added a new folder. That's why I'd rather use a generic location block instead of multiple ones.

Comment: @FilipeKiss An index file is the index of the directory it's in. You cannot have more than one. So each directory will need its own block where there will be an index.

Comment: Oh, I see. So I'll need multiple blocks for the index regardless. Thanks for the explanation. :)

Answer (score 2):

Keep it simple:

```
server {
    root /document/root/main/;
    index index.html;

    location /wishlist {
        root /document/root/;
    }
}
```