# Nginx replacement folder with try_files?

Tags: nginx

I'm trying to use `try_files` directive to provide following mechanism: I have a shared folder with static files:

```
.
├── _shared
│   └── assets
│       ├── favicon.ico
│       └── logo.png
├── website1
│   └── assets
│       └── favicon.ico
├── website2
│   └── assets
│       └── logo.png
└── website3
    └── assets
        └── hello.txt
```

My goal is: If requested file exist *website* folder, return it, else, if file exist in *_shared* folder, return it, else 404.

Eg:

- HTTP GET `website1.com/assets/favicon.ico` -> 200 (from `/website1/assets/favicon.ico`)
- HTTP GET `website1.com/assets/logo.png` -> 200 (from `/_shared/assets/logo.png`)
- HTTP GET `website2.com/assets/favicon.ico` -> 200 (from `/_shared/assets/favicon.ico`)
- HTTP GET `website2.com/assets/logo.png` -> 200 (from `website2/assets/logo.png`)
- HTTP GET `website3.com/assets/hello.txt` -> 200 (from `website3/assets/hello.txt`)
- HTTP GET `website1.com/assets/hello.txt` -> 404

Is it possible to do that with `try_files` ? How ? If not, is it possible to do with something else ?

Note: Tryied [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9286341/nginx-try-files-folders-files-fallback?rq=1) without success.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Following configuration working, eg. for `website1`:

```
location /assets {
    root /website1;
    try_files $uri @default_assets;
}

location @default_assets {
    root /_shared;
}
```